# Young black girl shot at basketball-court, leg twitch

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for a movie -- probably from the 1990s or 2000s.  I don't really remember much about it, though I *think* it revolves around a boy 12-16(?) growing-up in a "bad negihbourhood" and trying to avoid crime and drugs.

Anyway, there is this one scene where some kids/teens are playing basket-ball at an outdoor-court (possibly in a park).  The boy is standing on the sideline and looks at this.  Suddenly some gang-members (or something) shows-up and start shooting -- probably against a member from another gang.

A young girl -- guess about 11-13 -- gets hit, possibly in the head.  She goes down, and while she bleeds out, one of her legs keeps twitching in spasms... for about a minute before it stops and she dies.  I think most (if not all) the people around the court runs away, except the boy who stands close by and looks at the dying girl.  I think the girl is dressed in white.  I think she's dressed in a skirt.

Does this scene sounds familiar to anybody?  Does anybody know what movie this is from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for [Fresh](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109842/combined) (1994). It's been ages, but I still remember that scene vividly.

> Michael (or Fresh as he's well known) is a 12-year-old drug pusher who lives in a crowded housing project with his cousins and aunt. His father has become a street bum, but still meets with Fresh on occasion to play chess. Fresh is rather quiet in a crazy world. Fresh's sister is a junkie who sleeps with the dealers who Fresh sells for. As the story progresses Fresh realizes that he doesn't want to sell drugs anymore, he wants out.

The girl is Rosie, who has a sort of crush on Fresh. As she comes to talk to him in a basketball court, she gets caught in the crossfire of a dispute and the scene then unfolds exactly as you've described it. You can see it briefly in the trailer around 0:25:

Comment: Yep, definitively the one!  Thank you so much (it's been bugging me for a while).